# How to restate some theorems in the preface of a thesis?

Tags: theorems, thesis, report

In a PhD thesis we have to write a preface wherein some significant theorems from the main body of the thesis are needed to be restated. The amstools or thm-restate package does not help me in this regard. In this package the restated theorem must appear after the original theorem is stated. Till date I am doing it manually. But then the problem is if I change something in the original theorem then the same change must be done in the restated theorem also but manually. Is there any efficient method to do it?

Comment: Her is a solution, assuming that they are all theorems: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/356665/3929